# netbeans debugging pretty display string/vector

Tags: c++, debugging, variables, netbeans

is there any way, that the debugger in netbeans directly shows me the content of string variables?
Currently, If I press on the small "+" left of the variable name it shows me things like "npos, _M_dataplus, _M_string_length ...". It would help a lot to simply show me the content of the sting instead.

Same happens if I have a vector. In this case it is really a pain to debug variables becaus I always have to search for the content...

(I use NetBeans IDE 8.2)

Thanks

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slMdI.png)

Comment: no one? With my linux machine everything works fine. I have this problem only at windows

Comment: I have the same problem in Netbeans with C++ 4.9 remote compiler in centos